# Selenium, Java. Need to select ancestor element inside table by Xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have an HTML page containing the following code :

```
<table class="report" style="width:100%">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th/>
         <th>Position Open
            <br>
            <span class="timestamp">27/7/2016 16:12:12</span>
            </br>
         </th>
         <th>Position closed
            <br>
            <span class="timestamp">27/7/2016 16:12:42</span>
            </br>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <span dir="ltr">EURJPY</span>
         </td>
         <td>116.098</td>
         <td>116.156</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

On this page I have another table with the same class attribute "report" but only this table contains texts "Position Open" and "Position Closed".
I need to select elements containing the "EURJPY", "116.098" and "116.156" data.
These elements content is changing i.e. instead of "EURJPY" may appear "EURUSD" or "GBPCAD" etc.
I tried the following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Position Open']/ancestor::table[@class='report'](//tr)[2]/td/span")).getAttribute("textContent");
```

to get the first required field text but got the `Invalid selector` error.

Comment: I think you shold try to remove brackets in `(//tr)`

Comment: Your xpath and the logic for your requirements is clear.  Do you mean "Position Open" *OR* "Position Closed"? Your attempt only tests for Position Open.   Also, you say you want to select elements, but the FindElement() only selects a single element, and your example suggests you only want the text contained in the span.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XPath is close but there were a couple issues.

```
//span[text()='Position Open']/ancestor::table[@class='report'](//tr)[2]/td/span
```

1. You are searching for a `SPAN` that contains the text 'Position Open' when in fact it is a `TH` that contains the text.

   ```
   //th[text()='Position Open']/ancestor::table[@class='report'](//tr)[2]/td/span
   ```
2. `(//tr)` should be corrected to `//tr`

   ```
   //th[text()='Position Open']/ancestor::table[@class='report']//tr[2]/td/span
   ```
3. What you want is the text contained in the `TD`, not the `SPAN`. If you pull the text from the `TD` you can get the text you want from all three elements. If you pull the `SPAN`, then you will also need to pull the last two `TD`s. This way is just simpler.
4. ...and finally, the `TH` contains more than just the text you are looking for. Use `.contains()` to get a match.

   ```
   //th[text()='Position Open']/ancestor::table[@class='report']//tr[2]/td
   ```

So we take that XPath and put it into Java code and we get the below.

```
List<WebElement> tds = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//th[contains(text(),'Position Open')]/ancestor::table[@class='report']//tr[2]/td"));
for (WebElement td : tds)
{
    System.out.println(td.getText());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There can be issues matching the text sometimes, use contains instead, try this selector

```
//th[contains(.,'Position')]/ancestor::table[@class='report']//tr[2]/td/span
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `xpath` to locate the 3 `<td>` tags you are interest in

```
//th[contains(text(),'Position Open')]/ancestor::table//tr[2]/td
```

Using it will give you list of three elements, you can extract the text from them

```
List<WebElement> tds = driver.findElement(By.xpath"//th[contains(text(),'Position Open')]/ancestor::table//tr[2]/td");
String currency = tds.get(1).getText(); // this will be EURJPY
tds.get(2).getText(); // 116.098
tds.get(3).getText(); // 116.156
```